# Counting nodata and data pixels using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, clip, postgis-raster, intersect

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.4 and PostGIS 2.0.3.

I have some raster layer and I'm trying to get the count of all pixels (including nodata), cliped by polygon.

Raster was imported by raster2sql:

```
raster2pgsql -I -d -C -M -s ESPG_code -t 80x80 input_source > output.sql
psql -h localhost -U user_name -d database -f output.sql
```

So my code is:

`WITH 
    polygon As (
        SELECT ST_GeometryFromText('wtk_polygon_geometry))', epsg) As geom
    )

SELECT
    ST_Count(ST_Clip(r.rast,p.geom),1,false) As val
FROM
    raster As r,
    polygon As p
WHERE
    ST_Intersects(r.rast,p.geom)`

and I'm geting overestimated value and it looks like below.
[image]

but the query should output a count value looks like this - non highlighted pixels:[image]

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your requirement to the counted raster cells is. In the text you write that you want the raster cells that intersect the polygon, but in your figure you implement another rule, which looks like you only want raster cells that are covered by more than 50% of the polygon. Please edit your question to clarify this.
But couldn't you set the `ST_Clip` option `crop` to `true` to get only raster cells that are intersected by the polygon (question as per the text)?

Comment: I mean that i would like to have count only pixels cliped by some polygon layer (also the nodata 'pixels'). So for now I have several extra unnecessary pixels. I didn't specified crop for true because the output raster is crop anyway.

Comment: I believe I'm trying to solve the same problem as @joe_dz To clarify, do you mean that there are some nodata pixels inside the clipped area as well as some nodata pixels outside of the clipped area and that you only want to count pixels with data inside the clip + nodata pixels inside the clip (i.e. total number of pixels inside the clip even if they are nodata)?